# Python: Making a class variable static even when a module is imported in different ways

Tags: python, class, static, import

Let's consider the package structure as below:

```
myApp
|-- myPackage
|    |-- __init__.py 
|    +-- myModule.py
|-- __init__.py
+-- main.py
```

myModule.py contains a single class such as:

```
class MyClass( object ):
    _myList = []

    @classmethod
    def test( cls ):
        cls._myList.append( len( cls._myList ) )
        return cls._myList

    def __init__( self ):
        return

    pass
```

As you can see, there's nothing fancy, I'm just defining a list as a static class variable.
Now let's consider the code from main.py:

```
from myApp.myPackage.myModule import MyClass as MyClassAbs
from myPackage.myModule import MyClass as MyClassRel

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print '\n  myList'
    print 'MyClassAbs().test():', MyClassAbs().test() #< Prints [0].
    print 'MyClassRel().test():', MyClassRel().test() #< Prints [0] but should be [0, 1].
    print 'MyClassAbs.test():', MyClassAbs.test() #< Prints [0, 1] but should be [0, 1, 2].
    print 'MyClassRel.test():', MyClassRel.test() #< Prints [0, 1] but should be [0, 1, 2, 3].

    print '\n  myList ids'
    print id( MyClassAbs().test() )
    print id( MyClassRel().test() )
    print id( MyClassAbs.test() )
    print id( MyClassRel.test() )

    print ''
    print 'MyClassAbs == MyClassRel:', MyClassAbs == MyClassRel #< Prints False
    print 'isinstance( MyClassAbs(), MyClassRel ):', isinstance( MyClassAbs(), MyClassRel ) #< Prints False
    print 'isinstance( MyClassRel(), MyClassAbs ):', isinstance( MyClassRel(), MyClassAbs ) #< Prints False

    pass
```

The issue is that in my code I'm importing twice the same class from the same module but in different ways: once as a an absolute import and once as a relative one. As seen in the last part of the code, even though the classes are the same, they are not equal because their module are being registered distinctively into the sys.modules:

```
'myApp.myPackage.myModule': <module 'myApp.myPackage.myModule' from '/full/path/myApp/myPackage/myModule.py'>
'myPackage.myModule': <module 'myPackage.myModule' from '/full/path/myApp/myPackage/myModule.py'>
```

and as a result, their representation differs:

```
'MyClassAbs': <class 'myApp.myPackage.myModule.MyClass'>
'MyClassRel': <class 'myPackage.myModule.MyClass'>
```

So... is there any way to set this variable as static for good?

**Edit:**
The code above is a obviously only a reduction of my real problem. In reality, I basically have a piece of code that inspects all the modules recursively nested within a folder and that registers the classes contained in there. All the classes registered this way can then be instanciated using a common syntax such as

```
myApp.create( 'myClass' )
```

This is why I sometimes end up having 2 objects pointing to the same class but that have been imported in different ways. One has been imported automatically through a imp.load_module() call, and the other would have been directly imported by the user through a conventional import statement. If the user decides to manually import a class, he should still have access to the same static class variable than the one defined within the same but automatically registered class. Hope it makes sense?

Comment: I've obviously got no interest to use a such code as it is - this snippet is just a reduction of the problem that I'm having, but next time I can copy/paste my the XXXX lines of my code if you prefer?

Comment: Mine's not quite the answer to your question but might still be relevant so i'll leave it; so on rereading: is it that, for some reason, two different parts of your code import the module then want to share the same (module level) variable?

Comment: How are you using `load_module`?  That function provides a `name` argument where you're supposed to specify the module name (which will be the key in `sys.modules`).  So if you specify the absolute module path (including the top-level package) then it should work.

Comment: Sure John, it sounds like a plan but I don't think it'll help... I'll try it out tomorrow, thanks!  
I thought about that BrenBarn but it's impossible to know by advance how the user will import the module (relatively or absolutely).

Comment: @ChristopherC: Relative imports (or rather, implicit relative imports) are deprecated starting in Python 2.6.  Just put in your library's documentation that users *must* use absolute imports and that doing otherwise will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: I'm trying to find more info about the deprecated relative imports but can't find anything, would you please have a link?

Comment: @ChristopherC: The adoption of [PEP 328 in Python 2.5](http://docs.python.org/2.6/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports) says " users should begin using absolute imports as much as possible".  Implicit relative imports were [removed in Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3.3/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.  (At least, not without very ugly and fragile hacks.)  When you import it in those two different ways, the module is actually imported twice.  Python usually re-uses an already-imported module if you import it again, but this is based not on the actual file imported, but on the path relative to `sys.path`.  So if you import `myModule.py` once absolutely and once relatively, the whole file actually gets executed twice.  You can see this if you do something like:

```
from myApp.myPackage import myModule
import myApp.myPackage.myModule as sameModule
import myPackage.myModule
print myModule is sameModule
print myModule is myPackage.myModule
```

You should see `True` for the first print (because the first two imports are via the same path) but `False` for the second (because the third import uses a different path).  This is also why you're seeing the module with two entries in `sys.modules`.

Because the whole module is imported twice, you actually have two different classes called MyClass, not one.  There's no legitimate way to have those two classes share their state.  It's just as if you'd imported two different classes from two different modules.  Even though they happen to be defined in the same source file, they're not linked in any way when you double-import them like that.  (There *is* an evil way to link them, which is that you can include code in your module to manually check if it's been imported under a different name, and then manually mess with `sys.modules` to set the currently-importing module to the already-imported one.  But this is a bad idea, because it can be hard to tell if what's being imported is really the same module, and also because stomping on `sys.modules` can lead to strange bugs if either the original import or the new import failed for any reason.)

The real question is, why are you importing the module twice?  The second question is, why are you using relative imports at all?  The solution is to just import the module once using absolute imports, and then you'll have no problems.

Comment: Thanks BrenBarn for your reply. I'm actually aware of all this, I was just hoping there was a trick somehow, using a keyword or a technique that I wasn't aware of.
I'll edit my question to explain what my real problem is.

Answer (score -1):

"static" variables in other languages have a lot to answer for when it comes to python.  I too find that way of thinking makes my head hurt when it comes to this language.

It's hard to tell what your ultimate goal is but it might be worth noting that you can make a 'static' variable - (|cough| a 'module' variable?) by declaring it in the module.  So myModule might be structured something like:

```
modList = []

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._myList = [len(modList),]

    def appendLenToModList(self):
        modList.append(len(self._myList))
```

The modList is initialized on the `import` and should serve you as a singleton/static var.  If you really want to mess with it directly I'm pretty sure you can even use it from myApp using the namespace `myPackage.myModule.modList`; but some accessors to formalize its use and purpose might be advisable.

Comment: This won't fix anything. The questioner's problem is that the module is being imported twice under different names (one absolute, one relative) and Python doesn't detect that they're from the same source file. Your module-level variable will have exactly the same problem as the class-level variable in the question.

Comment: Ok, I've tried anyways just to make sure and it indeed doesn't work, as expected.