# Changes to static class variable are not visible from another module

Tags: python, python-module, class-variables

I'm writing a Python package for some REST API. To make it easier to manipulate the state of the objects I get from the API, I want to store a static reference to my API client instance. Let's say I have a file `user.py`:

```py
class User:
    _client: Client = None
```

So when the client successfully authenticated for the first time, I update the reference:

```py
class Client:
    def authenticate(self):
        ...
        User._client = self
```

This happens in my `client.py` file. Now I can successfully access `User._client` from any function that was declared in `client.py`, but when I try the same thing from another module, `User._client` is still `None`.

Let's say this is my folder structure

```
└── my_api_client
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── client.py
    ├── search.py
    └── user.py
```

Then when I call `User._client` from a function in `search.py`, I get `None` instead of a reference to the current client instance.

I'm having trouble creating a minimal working example that demonstrates this issue, so maybe I just messed up something with my imports. I think it would really help if I understood better what exactly happens if I import a class from another module and if references to static attributes of that class are shared between all modules. If this is indeed the case, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post a code example of search.py to see how are you calling and what are your imports?

Comment: Is there a reason why you specifically want to dynamically change a static class variable? Judging from the lines provided I would assume that on connection a `User`-object is created that uses a client object. So instead of using the class variables the assingment needs to be done to the `userobject._client`.

Comment: I didn't manage to reproduce the issue outside of the application I'm developing, all of the above is just a simplified abstraction of what I'm doing. I would be grateful for any hints on what could go wrong in Python when using class variables and module imports though

Comment: @JonathanWeine I want the client reference on the class instead of the instance so I don't have to pass a client reference to the constructor each time I'm creating a `User` instance. This might be feasible in this case, but I have layers of classes that are deserialized automatically and injecting the client reference every time an instance gets created turned out to be quite difficult.

Comment: I somewhat fishing in the dark here, but it sounds like you are implementing something like a singleton pattern for the User. If that is the case (which usually is not the best choice especially if you want to do things in parallel at some point), instead of modifying the static class variable you could use a `global` User instance.

Comment: you can probably call it a singleton, not sure if it's exactly the same thing. I guess I can work around this whole issue by declaring a dict somewhere on module-level and just adding the stuff I want to statically access to that dict. But I would really love to know why my class variable doesn't work as expected ;)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce you issue, but could not.

```py
# user.py

print("defining class User")


class User:
    _client = None  # removed type annotation here to prevent circular import


print("right now, User._client is " + repr(User._client))
```

```py
# client.py

import user


class Client:
    def authenticate(self):
        user.User._client = self


print("instantiating a Client")
client = Client()
print("before athenticating, the User._client is " + repr(so70744003_user.User._client))
client.authenticate()
print("before athenticating, the User._client is " + repr(so70744003_user.User._client))
```

and running the file `client.py` :

```
defining class User
right now, User._client is None
instantiating a Client
before athenticating, the User._client is None
before athenticating, the User._client is <__main__.Client object at 0x7fc1816a9b20>
```

I can give you a detailed breakdown of what happened :

- Python was given the file `client.py` so started running the code in the file
- it starts with `import user` so Python will search for the `user` module and load it

  - Python does not have a builtin `user` module, so that it searches for it in its [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) directories, and find a matching file
  - Python starts running the `user.py` file, which defines a `User` class, so it instantiates a `class` instance for it (with a static member `_client` set to `None`), and binds it to the `User` name in the current module
  - then it prints that `User`'s static member `_client` is indeed `None`
  - having finished running the `user.py` file, Python resumes running the `client.py` file
- the import succeeded, so Python has a `module` object and binds it to the `user` name in the current module scope (`client`)
- continuing running the file, a class definition is encountered (with a method defined) and it gets binded to the `Client` name in the current module
- then it instantiates a `Client` and binds it to the `client` name in the current module (named `client` too)
- it then calls `authenticate`, which sets `user`(the name of the variable pointing to the module loaded from `user.py`)`.User`(the class in the module)`._client`(the static variable in the class) to `self`
- finally it prints that the static variable new value is actually an instance of `Client`

In you question's comments, it was suggested to use a `global` variable. It would change nothing, because your `User` class is essentially already a **singleton** (there is only one declared), you just happen to access one of its fields. A singleton's fields can be considered singleton values too.

I don't know what is the problem with your implementation, you did not gave us enough to find the bug. If you want to find it, I recommend to try to reduce it to a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Usually in the process, you will find the solution yourself.

I fear it could be caused by mutual imports, such that the state of the variable depends on the order of import statements in every file of the project. It's a reason to try to break cycles, or be careful around them.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description! That's pretty much how I would expect my application to behave, only it doesn't for some reason that I don't understand. Unfortunately, I failed to create a Minimal Reproducible Example and I can't paste all of my code here :/

Comment: What you can do is add a lot of logging, or run step-by-step with a debugger. Your [mental model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mental_model) of how your code runs is wrong, and you will have to find the discrepancy. Also, [rubber duck programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) (or with a human) may help too.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be having an issue with how your class *User* is being imported in *search.py* and *client.py*. If you are importing the User module in these files using different paths, then they get loaded as different class names (hence loaded twice). As each loading executes the User class code, you might endup getting *_client* initialized twice to None. You can find more details of this issue [in this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392038/python-making-a-class-variable-static-even-when-a-module-is-imported-in-differe)

Another possible reason is that your code might be explicitly making import and module reload calls. Some frameworks that dynamically load modules tend to make these kinds of calls to load modules. A forced reload of *User* class would cause *_client* to be set to None

Comment: I did not know one file could give two different modules if imported in two different ways. For me, that's yet another reason to prefer canonical imports (`myapp.mypackage.mymodule`) and avoiding static values (when reasonably possible).